# What is the name for a chef's hat?

Tags: language

I would like to know what the long hat that chef's wear is called.

Toque is what Google/Wikipedia proffer but is it really that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it is called a toque.  I don't have a copy of CIA Pro Chef handy at the moment, but it was in the first chapter IIRC. Wikipedia and a casual googling will confirm this.

Answer (score 3):

Toque is from French after the Spanish word toca; which is a word for various kinds of hat.

Comment: I think it's derived from "tocus" after the kind of people who wear chef hats.

Comment: "tocus" also refers to a very different body region.....